# Managing Intervals and Ranges in LUIS App

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am creating a querying LUIS App, which needs a semantic understanding of time/ date ranges.

By semantic, I mean that I would like to be able to resolve the following examples:

```
Last week -> start: 2019-09-02T00:00:00+00:00; end: 2019-09-08T00:00:00+00:00

Yesterday -> start: 2019-09-14T00:00:00+00:00; end: 2019-09-14T23:59:59+00:00

1st July to the 18th August -> start: 2019-07-01T00:00:00+00:00; end: 2019-08-18T00:00:00+00:00
```

I have tried the built in `datetimev2` entity, however, that doesn't appear to contain the range functionality and the custom entities don't seem to be able to manage resolving a single utterance - i.e. "yesterday" and resolve that to 2 different values (i.e. `start` and `end`). Whereas the 3rd example, 2 specific values are obviously fairly straight forward to  manage.

The only current solution I can currently see is to have a "Range" entitiy, which `yesterday`, `last month` etc. would resolve too. As well as a `start` and `end` type. Then manually resolve the values in code outside the botframework. But this is a bit messy.

Are there any built it types or features which cover this sort of functionality, or is there an alternative approach to architect this?

**NOTE:**
From the Azure docs, it seems as though the preferred solution is to use the prebuilt `datetimeV2` entity, with a "start" and "end" role. However, I can't get the app to identify the range as two entities i.e. it identifies "between 1st July and the 18th August" as one value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex entity for this scenario, create a Regex entity with start and end role : 
[image]

Config your intent:
[image]
[image]

Test : 
[image]

The regex expression here is :

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})
```

Which matches date format YYYY-MM-DD . Hope it helps .

Comment: May I know is it helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the datetimeV2 prebuilt entity, 'Yesterday' will result in a single value as date. Something like

```
"entities": [
{
  "entity": "yesterday",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
  "startIndex": 14,
  "endIndex": 22,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "2019-09-16",
        "type": "date",
        "value": "2019-09-16"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

For this scenario (wanting a range for a single date), my suggestion is to take the returned resolution and use your favorite/appropriate library to calculate the range. i.e. use the value `2019-09-16` to be a date-time range.

But using the utterance 'between 1st july and the 18th august', it should resolve to a daterange:

```
"entities": [
{
  "entity": "between 1st july and the 18th august",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange",
  "startIndex": 14,
  "endIndex": 49,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "(XXXX-07-01,XXXX-08-18,P48D)",
        "type": "daterange",
        "start": "2019-07-01",
        "end": "2019-08-18"
      },
      {
        "timex": "(XXXX-07-01,XXXX-08-18,P48D)",
        "type": "daterange",
        "start": "2020-07-01",
        "end": "2020-08-18"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

datetimeV2 uses the Recognizers-Text library (and Timex for datetime) and you can find more info [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text). You can find a Node sample on how to work with Timex [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/40.timex-resolution).